# Identify ~6-7mm long green creature

Tags: entomology, species-identification

[image: Here is the creature]

Here is the creature I found on the glass lid of my light bulb. I guess they are attracted to light as they all concentrate on the light source. I live in Hong Kong. The brown things aren't moving (those might be eggs). The green creatures are about 0.6-0.7 cm long in body length (excluding appendages and antennae). They are sluggish in movement.

Can you help me to identify these tiny creatures?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Can you please try to add some information. For example: Where do you live? What size are those? Can you tel us more about their behaviour? Are the browns things alive or is food or is it just stain on your light bulb?

Comment: I don't have much information about it. My mum fear it will spread and so I clear them away immediately after I take the photo. I live in hong kong. They are about the size in the original photo here (no magnification). And the brown, oval things I suppose are their eggs. They are sluggish in movement and I clear them easily. The eggs are kind of sticky.

Comment: I edited your post to include those info and make few other modifications. Feel free to rollback if you don't like my edits. +1

Comment: This is the first time I use this platform to post question. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Yep, I know that feeling! This is all good! Thanks for the extra info. I personally have no idea what it could be but I am not a good naturalist!

Comment: I see 14 eggs and 14 individuals They must have _just_ hatched, which will make identification very difficult.  Maybe [Miridae](http://bugguide.net/node/view/94/bgpage) ?

Comment: Good observation. So one likely possibility is their adult form can fly and it reach the light bulb to lay the eggs. The larvae hatched and it seems it was an unsuitable environment for them and so they appear sluggish.

Comment: Based on its morphology, it should be evolutionarily adapted to living in aquatic environment I guess.

Comment: I have no idea what they are, but they are fascinating looking and rather beautiful in their way. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is an insect (6 legs) and a seems like a nymph (hatchlings that are not larval); if they really are hatchlings. There are a [few family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph_%28biology%29) of insects that hatch this way. You may have a look at them. Seems like green mirid but could be baby crickets too (I am not an expert in this area).

Comment: Amazing nature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's take a look at the magnified body of the insect (it is a nymphe btw) - we can see 2 brown dots one above the other along the body line. This pattern is very suggestive to Chelinidea species (the most common is ***Chelinidea vittiger aequoris***):

[image]

I stop my search at **Coreidae** family, because multiple species (a lot of bugs actually) of this family have similar appearance, for example:

***Gonocerus acuteangulatus***:

[image]

But other enthusiasts can start from here (Coreidae family) and trace it down more precisely - I am sure they will succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. I will research on it further to evaluate this possibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. Execellent picture quality of those creatures.